# Bat file doesn't work correctly

Tags: command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, winrar

I have this command on my bat file

```
"c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" a -agDD.MM.YYYY -cfg- -ep -p"123" "C:\Backup_.rar" "E:Backup"
```

as you see I'm running winrar to compress my file.
It works correct if I interactively run it on the Command Prompt but as I want to start .bat file with task scheduler it will compress the directory that the .bat file is located in It.
There is no error to show you. my problem is that when I run the task the source path will change. I should mention that my source path is not restricted and Everyone can access to It.
I would be happy if anybody can help.

Comment: We can’t help you if you don’t tell us what the problem is.  First of all, to be clear, are you saying that you have a batch file that contains that `rar` command, and *the batch file works correctly* when you run it interactively from the Command Prompt?  What if you `start` it from an interactive Command Prompt?  So, what happens when you try to run it through the scheduler?  Is the batch file running?  (Are you sure?)  Is the `rar` command failing?  Giving an error message?  Provide details.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Could it be that the Task Scheduler runs your batch file task under the SYSTEM account and that the drive letter E: is actually mapped to a network location?

Comment: No It's not a mapped drive. I just want to move my important files from drive C. and they should be compressed.

Comment: Try running it at a PowerShell script instead, PowerShell in my experience is a lot less bitchy about acting across drives. Just open a PowerShell terminal, enter `Set-ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted"`, 
rename the file from `myscript.bat` to `myscript.ps1`, then run the script. If you're paranoid, when you're done, finally do `Set-ExecutionPolicy "Default"`

Comment: Oh also, if my above advice doesn't work, try adding `& ` to the start of the command. This is, afaik, just for powershell, and usually required when running .exe files directly.

Answer (score 0):

use a change directory command

Can you show more of your script?  Are you using a change directory command? e.g. "CD C:\blah"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Start` command instead of just running the executable directly?

ex:

```
Start "WinRar" /wait "c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" a -agDD.MM.YYYY -cfg- -ep -p"123" "C:\Backup_.rar" "E:Backup"
```

if the above doesn't work, try surrounding the entire command in double quotes like this:

```
Start "WinRar" /wait ""c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" a -agDD.MM.YYYY -cfg- -ep -p"123" "C:\Backup_.rar" "E:Backup""
```

Great documentation on `Start` here: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Also, probably doesn't matter but, I noticed there isn't a slash in `"E:Backup"`